# How to call seperate file dart

Tags: flutter, widget

I want to make a condition when I press the button, it will shows pop up. But, beacuse I don't want the code to be long, I create the method on the other file. Unfortunately, the button did not respond anything.

This is where I put the method.

```
class AddItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const AddItem({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: popUpDialog(context),
    );
  }

  popUpDialog(BuildContext context) {
    TextEditingController customController = TextEditingController();

    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: const Text('Add Item'),
            content: TextField(
              controller: customController,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'Item Name'),
            ),
            actions: [
              MaterialButton(
                child: const Text('Add Item'),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
            ],
          );
        });
  }
}
```

And this is where I call the method.

```
Expanded(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 550, right: 55),
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                            backgroundColor:
                                const Color.fromARGB(229, 58, 0, 229),
                            minimumSize: const Size(50, 50)),
                        child: Row(
                          children: const [
                            Icon(Icons.add_box_outlined),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 15,
                            ),
                            Text('Add New Item'),
                          ],
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          const AddItem();  // <----- AddItem class from seperate file
                        },
```

Any suggestion what should I do, guys?

Comment: You want to call a Widget inside a Button?

Comment: show me your folder tree

Comment: You can take a look

Comment: No, it is not a widget. I want the condition when I press the button, it will show pop up. Somethin' like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call a Widget in onPressed, you should call the function directly

```
Expanded(
            child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 550, right: 55),
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(229, 58, 0, 229),
                      minimumSize: const Size(50, 50)),
                  child: Row(
                    children: const [
                      Icon(Icons.add_box_outlined),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 15,
                      ),
                      Text('Add New Item'),
                    ],
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    popUpDialog(context);  // <----- Function from seperate file
                  },
                )))
```

and in the seperate file

```
popUpDialog(BuildContext context) {
  TextEditingController customController = TextEditingController();

   showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: const Text('Add Item'),
          content: TextField(
            controller: customController,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'Item Name'),
          ),
          actions: [
            MaterialButton(
              child: const Text('Add Item'),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          ],
        );
      });
}
```